# Trouble installing PgBouncer (postgresql12-libs)

Tags: postgresql, centos7, yum, pgbouncer

I'm trying to install **pgbouncer** on Centos 7 but it seems to be a dependency problem.

pgbouncer requires **python2-psycopg2-2.8.3-1.rhel7.1.x86_64 (pgdg12)** and this one needs 
**postgresql12-libs** which can't be found.

I've got this postgresql repos:

```
pgdg10/7/x86_64                                                                PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                                                                1.062
pgdg11/7/x86_64                                                                PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                                                                  887
pgdg12/7/x86_64                                                                PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                                                                  171
pgdg94/7/x86_64                                                                PostgreSQL 9.4 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                                                                 979
pgdg95/7/x86_64                                                                PostgreSQL 9.5 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                                                               1.056
pgdg96/7/x86_64                                                                PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                                                               1.089
```

It's a repository problem or can I do something about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make bug report for repository maintainer.

To fix you can install previous version of python2-psycopg2

```
yum install python2-psycopg2-2.8.2 pgbouncer
```

Comment: Thanks, you point me in the right direction. 

I had to disable pgdg12 repo and then it worked!